# Is there a way to get date period on Google Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am thinking of migrating from Dialogflow to Actions, but I can't seem to find how to migrate system entity "Date period" to actions. I need the ability for the users to ask for a certain period.

Example: What is happening next month or Is there anything happening in March?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily this entity type was removed from AoG builder.

I faced the same issue, I've tried to contact support team without any response and I solved using DateTime, I know that the DatePeriod entity was really useful like so many other entity types that are been removed.

Looking at the new Dialogflow console and the Action Bilder samples, the only way to handle Dates is using DateTime, Date, Time entities. You can find further info [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#datetime_date_and_time_usage).

If you find any different solution, let me know!

Comment: Thank you @7laria, I ended up with not moving over to AoG builder. I would love to do it, but without the ability to easily define an date period I could not move over as most of our queries is based on a month or a date period (next week)